# How to create new issues without selecting 'project'(manually select project_id)?

Tags: python, django

[image]I am doing my school project by using Django to create a task management web application. My responsibilities are to create 'issue tracker', something like 'StackOverflow', but I am still at the very early stage of it. So I used crispy form to let the user create their own new issues. Since we use 'project_id' and 'issue_id' as parameters to direct users to different pages, so I encountered this problem, users have to manually choose 'project' when they create a new issue. I do not know how to put the issue which created by the user under right project without having to choose 'project' manually.

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment,Issue

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)

class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ('title','content','project','status')

class NewIssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Issue
        fields = ('title','content','project','status')
```

new_issue.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Add New Issue </h1>
    <form method="POST" class="Issue-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Issue, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project:issue_tracker:issue_detail', kwargs={'project_id':self.project_id, 'issue_id':self.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('',views.list_of_issue,name='list_of_issue'),
    path('<int:issue_id>/',views.issue_detail,name='issue_detail'),
    path('<int:issue_id>/comment',views.add_comment,name='add_comment'),
    path('new_issue/',views.new_issue,name='new_issue'),
    path('<int:issue_id>/edit_issue/',views.edit_issue,name='edit_issue'),
    path('<int:issue_id>/delete_issue/',views.delete_issue,name='delete_issue'),
    path('<int:issue_id>/delete', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="issue_tracker/issue/nice_delete.html"), name='success_deletion'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an *initial value* for the project field in the issue form. An explanation of how that can be done can be found [here](https://djangobook.com/tying-forms-views/#setting-initial-values).

Since you are using `project_id` and `issue_id` as parameters, something similar to the following will solve your problem (I guess):

```
def new_issue(request, project_id, issue_id):
    .
    . 
    form = IssueForm(initial={'project': project_id})
    .
    .
```

Comment: This seems a very cool! And it works! Do you know how to disable this button, so user can not change their project manually? I attached a screenshot .  @Alfarhan Zahedi

Comment: Just use this line after `form = IssueForm(initial={'project': project_id})` - 
`form.fields['project'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True `